# Pax Exam 2.6.0 + Karaf 2.3.0 - Debugging in Eclipse fails - NotBoundException

Tags: eclipse, debugging, integration-testing, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I have been using Pax Exam 2.6.0 for running integration tests on Apache Karaf 2.3.0 via the **Karaf Exam Container**.

Everything works as expected, except for local debugging (not remote) of an integration test from Eclipse.
I found a proposed solution here: 
http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/FAQ#FAQ-WhydoestheJavadebuggernotstopatabreakpointIsetinmyPaxExamJUnittest%3F

> When working with the Pax Runner container, you are dealing with two
>   Java VM processes, one running the test driver, and one running the
>   OSGi framework. The execution flow of your JUnit class is actually
>   split between the two VMs, and the bodies of your test methods are
>   executed on the remote VM.
>
> So you need to enable remote debugging for the spawned VM using a
>   vmOption() in your @Configuration method, e.g.
>
> vmOption("-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"),
>   systemTimeout(0)

Unfortunately that doesn't work, when I try to launch a JUnit test from Eclipse in debug mode I keep getting these errors for each @Test - annotated method which runs:

```
java.rmi.NotBoundException: c59ea59a-f771-47fe-aac8-aa7f5c72b17d
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:136)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.getRemoteBundleContext(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:263)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.waitForState(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:234)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.exam.container.internal.KarafTestContainer.waitForState(KarafTestContainer.java:599)
    at org.apache.karaf.tooling.exam.container.internal.KarafTestContainer.start(KarafTestContainer.java:183)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.AllConfinedStagedReactor.invoke(AllConfinedStagedReactor.java:67)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner$2.evaluate(JUnit4TestRunner.java:285)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The only thing displayed in the Console view is the following line:

> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

My system details are the following:

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Java version: Oracle Java 7 Update 9 64bit
- Pax exam version: 2.6.0
- IDE: Eclipse 4.2

This problem happens every time.

As a conclusion: my goal is to be able to run the jUnit integration tests directly from Eclipse IDE in Debug mode. 
Does anybody have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add this inside your Option [] cfg.

KarafDistributionOption.debugConfiguration("8889", true)